# importing color into Google Calendar

Tags: events, colors, google-calendar-api

I want to import events into Google Calendar, and I want them colored. A CSV import will not do it (color is not one of the recognised fields). So I thought I would try an iCal import instead. Looking at the iCal format, it appeared that whilst I couldn't set the color of an event, I could set the color of the whole calendar. Since I only want two different colors, I could just generate two different files for import. However, events still appear in the same color. Here is my sample import:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:Publish
X-WR-TIMEZONE:Europe/London
COLOR:105:50:34
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20130908T140000Z
DTEND:20130908T153000Z
SUMMARY:Communications Working Group
LOCATION:Conference Room 2
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20131006T140000Z
DTEND:20131006T153000Z
SUMMARY:Communications Working Group
LOCATION:Conference Room 2
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Is there a way to import event colors into Google Calendar?

Comment: Until Google switch to new iCal specification, there is no way to import/export colors without some kind of manually written script. RFC-5545 (used currently) simply doesn't support this option,, but newer RFC-7986 does.
https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5545
https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7986#section-5.9

PS: Yeah, I know. Golden shovel ;)